# Как изменить адрес страницы php?

Tags: php

подскажите как сделать такой адрес страницы, к примеру для блога, есть такая ссылка на статью test.ru/blogs/view.php?id=1 а нужно что бы было так test.ru/blogs/Test-statya , "Test-statya" из бд вместе id

Comment: во-первых, поднимаем глаза к адресу этой страницы и видим, что правильный адрес  это test.ru/blogs/1/Test-statya . Во-вторых, готовых ответов на этот вопрос в интернете примерно миллион

Comment: Не нашел норм ответов либо не правильно гуглил..., как это реализовать?

Comment: Надо учиться работать с информацией в интернете. Без этого программистом не стать.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^ index.php
```

index.php

```
$path = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/");
$pg = explode('/', $path);
print_r($pg);
```

Comment: что такое e()? Для чего нужны переменные $_GET["pg".$i]? Что за адова регулярка? Для чего вообще писать в $_GET?

Comment: Скопировал с собственного старого проекта, поправил убрал лишние.

Comment: и что, в каждом параметре встречается вопросительный знак, серьёзно?

Comment: теперь ещё лучше. можно поинтересоваться, чем, в итоге, массив $pg отличается от массива  $parts? ну кроме кривой индексации?

Comment: мда лоханулся конкретно видимо еще не проснулся =)

Comment: уже лучше. Осталось понять, зачем $1 в RewriteRule. И ^(.*)$, раз уж на то пошло

Comment: `$path = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/");` гораздо короче первых трех строчек